# Why does CMake prefixes spaces with backslashes when executing a command?

Tags: escaping, cmake

I have a custom command in a CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(testfiles "test1 test2")
add_custom_target(testtouch COMMAND touch ${testfiles})
```

When I run "make testtouch VERBOSE=1" I see that it executes :

```
touch test1\ test2
```

This is just an example, but I have this problem in a real project and the "\ " are breaking the command. Note that I get the variable (here testfiles) from a Find script and can't just get rid of the double quotes.

Why does CMake do that ?

How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because sometimes difference between cmake list variable type and cmake string literal become important.

Try to change the variable setup to the following to avoid the problem:

```
set(testfiles "test1" "test2")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't change the variable setup because I receive it from another script. Can I manipulate the variable in a way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Reply to myself: I used the following line to have it working : string(REPLACE " " ";" testfiles ${testfiles})

Comment: This holds even for passing options like "-o outfile". No chance to pass this as a string; we need to supply it as list "-o;outfile", however counterintuitive that is.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying something similar with multiple arguments some are strings and some are not, i.e.:

```
add_custom_target(externalProject COMMAND make -s VALUE1:="${argument1}" VALUE2:=${argument2} VALUE3:="${argument3}" ...)
```

Where `argument3` contained `"VAL1 VAL2 VAL3"`.

I found that replacing the spaces with semicolons `;` resolved the issue for me when `cmake` creates the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the comment by OP as an answer as it could have saved me some time. I was getting the value from environment variable and had no access to change it. So replacing spaces with quotes had to be done in CMake itself.

```
string(REPLACE " " ";" testfiles ${testfiles})
```